# Создание игры на svg хорошее решение?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, canvas, разработка-игр, svg

Здравствуйте, создал простенькую игру на svg, суть игры: с анимацией, циклично появляются цели(круги), необходимо на них нажимать, чтобы уничтожить, за уничтожение +1 к очкам, у цели есть время жизни, если не успеть сбить ее за это время, то -1 от очков. Это игра для развития аима(наводки мышкой). Хочу чтобы она была под все экраны, быстро работала. Знакомый сказал что лучше сделать это через canvas, а то из-за большого кол-ва dom элементов будет глучить. Наибольше из элементов у меня целей, но их будет максимум где-то 20. Подскажите правильнее сделать игру на canvas или svg хорошее решение?

[image: как выглядит игра]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для такого уровня графики решение правильное. Удобнее и быстрее дело пойдёт если взять Three.js или другую библиотеку WebGL. Но если начнёте работать с трехмерными моделями - начнёт ощутимо тормозить после примерно 50 тыс полигонов в сцене.

Еще лучше взять Unity 3D (или Unreal) - тогда один код можно будет компилировать и в Web, и на мобильные устройства. И возможности графики расширятся до примерно 1.5млн полигонов в сцене за счет того, что Unity будет кросс-компилировать в код Asm.js.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, игра будет 2d и только под десктопные устройства. То есть лучше выбрать svg из-за того что игра будет под все экраны? Почему не canvas?

Comment: я бы выбрал canvas

Comment: по той простой причине что любая игра должна содержать элементы художественной графики, для которой svg не очень подходит. Но если считаете что вам достаточно математической графики - берите svg. Вот забавный пример three.js + canvas - https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html